# Get request to a .html file is not handled by express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const bodyPar=require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const path=require('path');
var user=["Jared","Bill","Jason","Jeremy"];


app.use(express.static('proiect'));
app.use(bodyPar.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyPar.json());
app.use(session({secret:'secret',saveUninitialized:true,resave:true}));
var sess;
var s;

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    var i=0;
    sess=req.session;

    var username=req.body.username;
    var pass=req.body.password;
    var but=req.body.value;
    s=0;
    sess.email=username;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(username==user[i])
        {
            s=s+1;
            i=5;
        }
    }
    if(pass="123")
        s=s+1;
    if(s==2)
        res.redirect('homepage.html');
    else
        res.redirect('login-error.html');



    res.end();
});

app.get('/homepage.html',function(req,res){


        console.log('aaa');


});
app.get('bios.html',function(req,res){


        console.log('aaa');


});
app.post('/guest',function(req,res){
    sess=req.session;
    sess.username="Guest";
    s=2;
    res.redirect('homepage.html');
});
app.get('/logout',function(req,res){
    req.session.destroy(function(){
       res.redirect('login.html');  
       s=0;
    });

});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`));
```

The server doesnt handle the app.get('homepage.html') or 'bios.html' it just displays the html file in the browser.(should hang and display smth on console).

Am i supposed to serve/render those files instead of directly accessing them in the browser?
Both of those files are in the /proiect/ folder i've included on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express finds the static HTML file and then returns that to the user. Therefore it skips the route handler you wrote.

If you are trying to perform some server-side logic and returning an HTML page, rather return the page inside your route handler to avoid such side effects. In this case, create your HTML file in a *templates* folder or something. Then you can put all your static resources in your *static* folder. So your structure would look something like this:

```
+ project_folder
   + static
      + css
         - style.css
      + js
         - app.js
   + templates
      - bios.html
      - homepage.html
      - login.html
      - login-error.html
   - app.js
```

Then your app.js would look something like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const bodyPar=require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const path=require('path');
var user=["Jared","Bill","Jason","Jeremy"];


app.use(express.static('static'));
app.use(bodyPar.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyPar.json());
app.use(session({secret:'secret',saveUninitialized:true,resave:true}));
var sess;
var s;

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/templates/login.html'));
});

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    var i=0;
    sess=req.session;

    var username=req.body.username;
    var pass=req.body.password;
    var but=req.body.value;
    s=0;
    sess.email=username;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(username==user[i])
        {
            s=s+1;
            i=5;
        }
    }
    if(pass="123")
        s=s+1;
    if(s==2)
        res.redirect('homepage');
    else
        res.redirect('login-error');



    res.end();
});

app.get('/homepage',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/templates/homepage.html'));
});

app.get('bios',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/templates/bios.html'));
});

app.get('login-error', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/templates/login-error.html'));
});

app.post('/guest',function(req,res){
    sess=req.session;
    sess.username="Guest";
    s=2;
    res.redirect('homepage');
});

app.get('/logout',function(req,res){
    req.session.destroy(function(){
       res.redirect('login');  
       s=0;
    });

});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: "Express finds the static HTML file and then returns that to the user. Therefore it skips the route handler you wrote."
THIS
Shouldve wrote a question regarding this behavior,since i never found any info regarding this kind of handling by express on the web.
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! It would be very messy if Express did support multiple handlers because you can only return a single response object to the client's browser.  If multiple methods could handle requests then we could never be certain about what response would be sent back. Hence why it chooses the first handler it finds.